# How to save canvas which include image?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to save my canvas which include image. I was trying use toDataURL, but it doesn't work on this case. The canvas is work to input the image inside.

HTML

```
<img src="bg.png" id="toIMG" />
<canvas></canvas>
<img alt="UNCHANGED" id="getCtx">
<span>Why does the img doesn't change?</span>
```

JS

```
window.onload = function(){
  var c, ctx, img, img2;
  c = document.querySelector("canvas");
  ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  img = document.getElementById("toIMG");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, c.width, c.height);

  img2 = document.getElementById("getCtx");
  img2.src = ctx.canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}
```

Comment: i think your using the toDataURL method wrong, you need to call it on your Canvas object and not on the 2D Part. like canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); or in your case c.toDataURL("image/png");

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running the function when window has loaded, run it when the img has loaded. Also, as @CrissCrossCrass has pointed out, `toDataURL` is a method of canvas but not context.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img
      id="toIMG"
      src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/120x120"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <canvas></canvas>
    <img id="getCtx" />
    <script>
      var c = document.querySelector("canvas");
      var img = document.getElementById("toIMG");
      var img2 = document.getElementById("getCtx");
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      img.onload = function() {
        c.width = img.width;
        c.height = img.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);
        img2.src = c.toDataURL("image/png");
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, you may want to set the `crossOrigin` attribute of the first img element to be `anonymous` to avoid tainted canvas. [Read more about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image)

Comment: Thanks it's work. But, doesn't work if file is on device storage (not work in file://storage/emulated/0/folder/...)

Comment: How are you getting this file path (file://storage/emulated/0/folder/...)?

Comment: The path is where I save my file. I save the file is there

Comment: Have a look at [FileReader.readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

Comment: I have see it. But, how to use for this case?

Comment: You may have to explain more in detail in your question or even start a new one. But for now, I have created this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-bouman-5n1e3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) for you to play around.

Answer (score 0):

I tried that and actually it's working. Share if the console drops any error. Then i'll update my answer depending on it.